# Grails limit database column size

Tags: database, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

In my Grails app I have a domain class that has a property

```
SearchPrivacy searchPrivacy = SearchPrivacy.PUBLIC
```

where SearchPrivacy is an enum

```
enum SearchPrivacy {
    PRIVATE('pr'), PUBLIC('pu');

    final String id

    SearchPrivacy(String id) {
        this.id = id
    }

    static getEnumFromId(String id) {
        values().find {it.id == id}
    }
}
```

according to the Grails docs, the mapped database column will store either `pr` or `pu` - the value of the `id` property. However, there doesn't seem to be a way to reduce the max length of the DB column. I've tried adding both of the following

```
static constrtaints = {
    searchPrivacy(size: 2..2, maxSize: 2)
}
```

But in the generated schema the column is still `varchar(255)`

Thanks,
Don

Comment: @Don , did you have your issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how this translates to grails, but in Java it would be done with the `@Column(length=2)` annotation on the property.

Comment: By "in Java" do you mean "in Hibernate"?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Your constraints only restrict what you can persist.</strike>

If you want to modify the actual SQL type that is persisted you need to declare a static property called 'mapping' in your domain class - much like you are already doing for your constraints. It will look something like this:

```
static mapping = {
  searchPrivacy type: SearchPrivacy, {
    sqlType: "char(2)"
  }
}
```

You should always be on the lookout when you see yourself using the sqlType attribute because you could lose the database independence you get from hibernate. (Remember, not all databases support the same types.)

You can also use the 'mapping' property to handle things like custom column names, composite keys and id generation strategies.

I hope this helps!

Comment: It's untrue that "constraints only restrict what you can persist". If you look at the Grails documentation for the constraints, many of them say "This constraint affects schema generation"

Comment: I have seen that in old documentation. I'll remove that.

Did the mapping property solve your problem?

Comment: @Don: it only affect IF you create a NEW database. For old database, it will do nothing and use the old column definition. That's how Hibernate works. I'm not sure about sqlType mapping of Brandon though.

Answer (score 0):

May well be a bug. Have you thought about filing a bug report?